# How to "group" column results with same property in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a couple of tables, the main table has a property called "id", and the thing table has a property called "id_main". A main item may have more than one things. A thing may only have one main. How do i do to get an array with every thing of a main? My query works, but returns as many things it has copies of main properties, each one with a different thing relationed. This is my query:

```
SELECT
    m.id
    , x.color
    , t.volume
    , t.age
FROM main m
LEFT JOIN extra x
ON x.id = m.id
LEFT JOIN thing t
ON t.id = m.id
WHERE m.id = 1234;
```

It's returning :

```
{id: 1234, color: 'red', volume: '8', age: '10'} 
{id: 1234, color: 'red', volume: '3', age: '25'} 
{id: 1234, color: 'red', volume: '19', age: '152'}
```

And I would like to get:

```
{id: 1234, color: 'red', things:[{volume:'8', age:'10'}, {volume:'3', age:'25'}, {volume:'19', age:'152'}]}
```

Or the closest possible. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using [aggragate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) and `GROUP BY`?

Comment: What datatype are you expecting that `things` field to be?

Comment: @Gabriel'sMessanger, I didn't yet, will give it a look, thanks

Comment: @Eggplant, I don't think I understood the question, an array? That was just an example of what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: @JedianMarcos An array doesn't give you the option to have `key : value` pairs in the way you suggested in your example, thus I was asking you about the datatype. Ana's solution works with two separate arrays, while you would need a `json` output field if you wished to have your data structured in a `key : value` fashion like your example. Anyways, it's as simple as using `json_agg` and `json_build_object()` instead of `array_agg`.

Comment: @Eggplant, Oh, yea, got it.Yes, at first I was looking for a json-like output, but I can use Ana's solution just as easily. Thank you so much anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are flexible about having 'volume' and 'age' split in 2 arrays, your select could look like this:

```
SELECT
    m.id
    , x.color
    , array_agg(t.volume) as t_volume
    , array_agg(t.age) as t_age
FROM main m
LEFT JOIN extra x
ON x.id = m.id
LEFT JOIN thing t
ON t.id = m.id
WHERE m.id = 1234
GROUP BY m.id, x.color;
```